# Invoice Generator, Generate invoice, save pdf to drive and send mail

Tags: google-apps-script

I have use App Script for invoice generator

Create invoice
save pdf to Google Drive
Send mail with PDF attachment

some invoice working great,
some of them dont sending

> Message may contain a virus Your message wasn't delivered to
> info@Compdomain.com because it may contain a virus. Learn how to
> check for and prevent viruses."

> The response was: 552 5.7.0 This message was blocked because its
> content presents a potential security issue. Please visit
> https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BlockedMessage to review our
> message content and attachment content guidelines.
> d19sor3986996lfl.187 - gsmtp

difference with good and bad invoice are only customer details, nothing special
where is issue?

Comment: There are some companies that have email systems that reject certain file types and often they can change that if you have something they really want.   Also often the email systems will flag messages because of the content.  I doubt that you would want such a script to control the content.

Comment: What service are you using to send the email, MailApp or GmailApp? How many automated emails have you sent to the domain that has blocked the email message?

Comment: i using Gmail for send mail.

one invoice is blocked and another working,
difference with invoices are customer information only

no problem with sending limit.
nothing at my opinion in content is danger,
customer domain
customer company name, id, mob number, mail mobile and product